# Python: Why am I getting a UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, file-io, python-unicode

I have the following code that search through files using RE's and if any matches are found it move the file into a different directory.

```
import os
import gzip
import re
import shutil

def regEx1():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/myfiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/NewFiles")
    regex_txt = input("Please enter the string your are looking for:")
    for x in (files):
        inputFile = open((x), "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        regex = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE)
        if re.search(regex, content)is not None:
            shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/David/NewFiles")
```

When I run it i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 367: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please could someone explain why this message appears

Answer (score 9):

In python 3, when you open a file for reading in text mode (`r`) it'll decode the contained text to unicode.

Since you didn't specify what encoding to use to read the file, the platform default (from [`locale.getpreferredencoding`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)) is being used, and that fails in this case.

You need to either specify an encoding that *can* decode the file contents, or open the file in binary mode instead (and use `b''` bytes patterns for your regular expressions).

See the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for more information.

Comment: where would i add the "b''"

Comment: @LWH91: Read the HOWTO to understand what that *means* first.

Comment: Python 3 has `open(fname, mode, encoding='whatever')`, Python 2 has `codecs.open(fname, mode, encoding='whatever')`

Comment: @JochenRitzel: Let's focus this on Python 3; no need to confuse matters more for the OP. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ive read it, understand the problem but still dont know how to fix it

Comment: As @MartijnPieters mentioned, amend the `inputFile = open(…)` line to specify file encoding as it clearly is not in `CP1252` (`UTF-8` perhaps?).

Comment: @LWH91: You need to figure out what encoding is used for that file. Sorry, I cannot do that for you. Once you figure that out, use `open(file, encoding='the_proper_file_encoding')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters any ideas how I could figure that out?

Comment: @LWH91: Lots of ways; the python way would be to use [`chardet2`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet2) to make an educated guess. It won't be 100% foolproof in it's detection though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with python 3x, but the below may work.

```
inputFile = open((x, encoding="utf8"), "r")
```

Comment: when i try that i get an error saying `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question here: 
[Python: Traceback codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213178/python-traceback-codecs-charmap-decodeinput-self-errors-decoding-table0)

But you might want to try:

```
 open((x), "r", encoding='UTF8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this solution. It helps me for another subject, I used :

```
exec (open ("DIP6.py").read ())
```

and I got this error because I have this symbol in a comment of DIP6.py :

```
 #       ● en première colonne
```

It works fine with :

```
exec (open ("DIP6.py", encoding="utf8").read ())
```

It also solves a problem with :

```
print("été") for example
```

in DIP6.py

I got :

```
Ã©tÃ©
```

in the console.

Thank you  :-)  .