# Open a XML to send to SOAP in Python

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap

I am implementing a client for interaction with a SOAP WebService. This WebService has two parameters: a string and an xml.
I am a beginner in development with python but I would like to know how I can get an xml file from my machine to send it to my client.
I Tried :

```
test = open('LCL.XML')  
test = test.read()
print(test)
```

But it did not work.

> ```
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
>  492: character maps to <undefined>
> ```

Comment: I'm a Perl guy, but a SOAP person, so I'd recommend using a library, for example: http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/ this will make things simpler

Comment: I'm using zeep for a SOAP request. But my question is about open a xml file. Thanks

Comment: What is not working? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Use a `xml module`, for instance: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242486/python-why-am-i-getting-a-unicodedecodeerror may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to read and xml file and get it ready for sending vis SOAP:

`import xml.etree.ElementTree
filename = 'whatever.xml'
result = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
xml_str = xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(result, encoding='utf-8')`

Then send xml_str in `zeep.Client.service.<your soap call>(..., xml_str, ...)`